# XNA Content DLL

Tags: xna

Where is the content DLL? When I try to build my game (using Primary Output from the Setup Wizard for both my game and content), it gives me this error:

Could not find file 'C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\XNA\PowerChampions\PowerChampions\PowerChampionsContent\obj\x86\Release\PowerChampionsContent.dll' 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

Anybody know how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of things you need to check to solve this error. Let's start with **cleaning and rebuilding** the whole XNA solution, the one containing an XNA project and an XNA Content project (you have both in your project right?).

Comment: Building the content project will take time proportional to the number of assets inside the project so be patient if you have lots of them (images, sound files, etc).